# (venv) identifier not showing in VS Code Insider's integrated terminal (WSL2 Ubuntu), but is showing in Terminal Preview

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal, python-venv

Hello folks of Stack Overflow,

Currently having an issue in which the (venv) identifier that traditionally appears in the terminal when activating a virtual environment in a Python is **not** appearing in my *Visual Studio Code - Insider's Edition* integrated terminal in a *bash shell* from *Ubuntu Preview on WSL2*.

For some reason, the (venv) identifier **does** appear in a *bash shell* from *Ubuntu Preview on WSL2* when running with [**Terminal Preview**](https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9N8G5RFZ9XK3).

Refer to the images below. Notice how **Terminal Preview** displays `(whatever)` in the **prompt** of the bash shell when the python virtual environment is active...
[image: Depiction of desired result in Terminal Preview]

[image: Depiction of undesired result in VS Code]

---

I suspect that the issue has to be somewhere in my VS Code's setting, but I don't know what setting could make this possible. I have outputted my `User > Settings.json` for VS Code but nothing that I set should have this effect.

```
{
    "editor.inlineSuggest.enabled": true,
    "editor.fontFamily": "'CaskaydiaCove Nerd Font', Consolas, 'Courier New', monospace",
    "editor.fontSize": 12,
    "editor.tabSize": 2,
    "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
    "[python]": {
        "editor.formatOnType": true
    },
    "C_Cpp.clang_format_fallbackStyle": "Chromium",
    "workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons",
    "workbench.colorTheme": "GitHub Dark Default",
    "terminal.integrated.fontSize": 12,
    "editor.accessibilitySupport": "off"
}
```

---

To clarify, the python virtual environment ***does appear*** to “work” as intended expect for this small issue.

Any insight *or* guidance would be appreciated. Thank you and happy holidays!

Comment: Alright it works now... I simply just restarted my whole computer. I wish I have a more detailed reason as to why, but it is what is!

Comment: @JialeDu Okay, will do! Sorry wasn’t entirely familiar with the protocol for closing an issue on Stack Overflow; was planning on figuring that out this evening. Thank you for the heads up! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I am not sure how this problem was solved, it’s seems restarting my machine finally gave me the desired outcome.

Comment: @JialeDu Just did! Apologies for the delay, I swear I had done so before. Thank you for the reminder.